# Is "mein Deutsch" a "correct" phrase?

Tags: word-usage

Obviously in English, you can say stuff like "My German is terrible," or equivalent. But how is it in German? Is the following expression "correct"?

> Mein Deutsch ist gut / schlecht / verbessert sich noch / usw.

(I realize that in this sense, the word "Deutsch" is synonymous with the word "Deutschkenntnis". So another way to phrase this question would be: can the word "Deutschkenntnis" be shortened to "Deutsch" in written as well as spoken German?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok. but there belongs an "H" in "schlecht". But there is nothing wrong about "mein Deutsch". You can write it, too.
EDIT: You've also messed up the letters in "Deutsch".

Comment: Please fix typos and don't address them in your answer. Instead you might add further content, e.g. about "Deutschkenntnis" and its proper use in same context.

Answer (score 17):

["*Deutsch"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsch) means *German language*. *[Deutschkenntnis](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutschkenntnis)* means the knowledge of the German language and the ability to use it. It is usually used in plural (Deutschkenntnisse). So *Deutsch* is not a shortend version of *Deutschkenntnisse* and they are not generally synonym!

Two examples:

> Ich lerne in der Schule Deutsch.
>
> Ich habe gute Deutschkenntnisse.

In your sentence though, they can be used synonymly:

> Mein Deutsch ist gut / schlecht / verbessert sich stetig / usw.
>
> Meine Deutschkenntnisse sind gut / schlecht / verbessern sich noch / usw.

---

The sentence "Mein Deutsch ist gut" is perfectly fine, by the way, it is even listed as example in [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Deutsch):

> "dein, euer, ihr, mein, sein Deutsch ist schlecht"